# RE: Android 4.0.4 shows folder count on Galaxy Note (Android 4.0.4) but not on Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 4.0.4)

Tags: applications

On my Samsung Galaxy Note (Android 4.0.4) it shows the count of items on the header of each folder. I love this feature. Why cannot I see this on my Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 4.0.4)?

Thanks, Timothy

Comment: Which folders? Those on the desktop? In the email client? Please clarify.

Comment: Without clarification from the OP this question we can only answer by guessing at what's being referred to.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a standard feature of the Launcher.

This has most likely been added by Samsung to their touchwiz build of the Galaxy Note - as such, it would not be possible to get this on your Galaxy Tab.